# Travelling to Mexico on B1/B2 USA visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, international-travel

I am from India, studying in the UK. I have a B1/B2 USA visa. I haven’t travelled to the USA.  Is it possible that if I can travel directly to Mexico from the UK without entering the USA, by using the USA visa?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. There are plenty of flights that allow this from the UK, and if you have a visa from countries such as the US like mentioned you can use this to enter Mexico.

> if you have a valid visa for countries like the USA, Canada, Japan and the UK, or if
>   you have a valid Schengen visa, you do not require a separate visa for up
>   to 180 days of stay in Mexico. ([source](https://indiausatravel.com/can-i-enter-mexico-with-a-us-visa-on-my-old-passport/places-visit-usa/), [another source](https://www.visatraveler.com/visa-guides/mexico-visa-requirements/))

Things to note: Your passport should be valid for 6 months beyond arrival, and you should check if the US visa the appropriate type. If the nature of your visit is tourism, you should have a visa that falls under this category for example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply.  It means I can travel to Mexico directly from Uk, even though I haven’t been to the USA and I am transitioning from USA? I am just being worried that if I travel, then they don’t let me enter Mexico. 

Comment: The official government have said as long as you have one of those countries visas, and it is valid, then you can enter :)

Comment: Ok that’s fine. Thank you so much 

Comment: @Mini No worries! I worry about this stuff a lot to so its good to get reassurance. Enjoy your trip!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was sure about it before but I have been reading about it and I read on some website that I can only travel if I am going to transit through USA.